# LED Status Readback Circuit

Tags: transistors, led

Sorry for such foolish question, but what is the behaviour of circuit below:

[image]

LED_ON is 3.3V logic control signal, LED_STATUS is output signal to MCU pin (GPIO).

When LED_ON is logic high and Q1 is open LED1 is ON and LED_STATUS = '0', but what will happen when LED_ON = '0'? Q2 will be closed, LED1 will be OFF, but what will be the state of LED_STATUS signal? Will it be +5V (logic high) or floating and why?

Comment: It'll pretty much float. If you need it at +5V, put an R (10k or higher) in parallel with the LED.

Comment: Thanks, i'm thinking about the same solution - enable internal pullup resistor in mcu that LED_STATUS signal is connected to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LED_ON is Low, Q1 will be off (not conducting), and LED_STATUS will be a little over 3 volts.  With no current, R2 will pull the LED anode up to +5V.  Due to the typical 1.8 volt forward voltage of the LED, LED_STATUS will be pulled above 3 volts - exact value will depend on whatever is connected to LED_STATUS.

By the way, your use of "open" and "closed" for the transistor is confusing, as an open switch does not conduct, and a closed switch does conduct - you are using "open" to mean "conducting"

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Sorry for these mess, definitely i mean "open" - conduct and "close" - not conduct. It's a problem of terms in english and my native language.

Answer (score 1):

It will be around 3.5V. The led will act like a normal diode, with a forward voltage drop of aprox 1.5V (it mostly depends on led's color).
If you plan to read LED_STATUS by a 3.3V uC, the input will read it as Logic High, but there is a risk that the led will light-up (due to the input protection diode of the GPIO). For a 5V uC there is no risk for the led to light-up, but the voltage might be too low for a Logic High level.